# Как воспроизвести звук в формате .Wav из ресурсов?

Tags: c#, winforms

В ресурсы запихнул файл в формате `.wav`

Пытаюсь воспроизвести его используя следующий код:

```
SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.тут_фай_из_ресурсов);
sp.Play();
```

Но в итоге получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как воспроизвести файл? ( не используя доп библиотек )

Comment: Значит, это не wav-файл. Или он действительно повреждён. Попробуйте этот файл открыть любым плеером. В своей программе попробуйте для тестов добавить в качестве ресурса какой-нибудь стандартный виндузовый звук из папки c:\windows\media - с ним работает?

Comment: Ну в плеере мой файл wav работает нормально, но при запуске из ресурсов получаю ошибку.

Comment: А это действительно `wav`, а не `mp3` и т. п.? И каким образом он добавлен в ресурсы?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Ну я ж не слепой! И различаю `wav` от `mp3`. Открыл свойства проекта, ресурсы, переместил туда файл.

Comment: Какой тип у `Properties.Resources.тут_фай_из_ресурсов`? Если string -то не подходит вообще. Если stream - сохраните его в файл (вместо play) и проверьте заголовок 44 байта (заголовок wav легко найти в интернете) Проверьте что б формат wav был PCM. вот https://audiocoding.ru/article/2008/05/22/wav-file-structure.html формат - опубликуйте в вопросе первые 22 байта в heх-е.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Вопрос решен! Проблема оказалась в самом файле. ( скачал другой) попробовал воспроизвести и получилось.